# Conflict between fontspec and geometry

Tags: fontspec, geometry, incompatibility

Using the option `lines=x` of `geometry` does not give the expected result when the `fontspec` package is used in the same document. For example, declaring `lines=40` does not result in 40 lines per page but 29:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lines=40}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This hapens with standard classes (`book`, `article`), but not with the KOMA classes nor with `memoir`.

Loading `geometry` before `fontspec` and using `newgeometry` instead of `geometry` produces the expected result, but I would like to know what the problem is and how to resolve it.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by putting `\normalsize` before geometry. For some reason fontspec changes the baselineskip, but it needs some investigation to find out why exactly.

Comment: that's odd, without geometry it's 13.6pt then 10pt after fontspec until begin document, then 13.6 again.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It is caused by the `\DeclareErrorFont` from eu2enc. You get the same problem without fontspec and e.g. LGR. The KOMA-classes are not affected as they patch \selectfont. So imho it is a geometry bug, it shouldn't rely on a correct baselineskip but call `\normalsize`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks now you say that, I've seen that before somewhere:-) yes geometry could do \normalsize but it's not clear that  fontspec really should be leaving a 10pt baselinskip in the preamble. eu2enc.def could do `\DeclareErrorFont{EU2}{lmr}{m}{n}{\baselineskip}` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: As I wrote LGR does the same. And I grepped and found quite a number of \DeclareErrorFont declaration -- and all with fix sizes (one of them in latex.ltx). Also it doesn't look right to set the *font*size to \baselineskip. And why is \baselineskip set to the fontsize when `\DeclareErrorFont` is used?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer agreed setting fontsize to baseline is wrong, shame, I'm not convinced declareerrorfont really needs to set the baselineskip at that point though, maybe i'll raise with the team....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Removing the baselineskip change from \DeclareErrorFont will help but I still think that geometry should set \normalsize before processing the option -- at least in the preamble. And perhaps document (also for heightrounded) that the baselineskip value can be false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\baselineskip` is "wrong" (10pt instead of 13.4pt) when geometry calculates the lines as an `\DeclareErrorFont` from the euenc package changes it.

It is a bit unclear if it is a latex "bug" that `\DeclareErrorFont` resets the `\baselineskip` but even without this change geometry can err. E.g. This example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lines=40}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

gives a different layout then this one

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lines=40}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I can imagine other szenarios and imho geometry can't catch all possible cases, so if you want to use the `lines` option (and `heighrounded`) you will sometimes have to help it a bit to get the correct/wanted line height. In your cases by issuing `\normalsize` before `\geometry{lines=40}`. Or by setting the option with `\newgeometry` only at the begin of the document.